# TypeScript in combination with BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze, hottowel

I'm currently working on a project prototype with TypeScript in combination with BreezeJS. I'm using the HotTowel template from John Papa and wrote my own TypeScript ViewModels for each HTML page.

To use normal JavaScript libs you need a TypeScript file file.d.ts which is some sort of interface class so TypeScript knows which JavaScript functions there are.

With this combination I'm trying to create a new entity but I can't find the function CreateEntity. This is located in my breeze.d.ts file but its not working. Intellisense is not autocomplete my statement.

So if I type `this.Manager.CreateEntity` it is not showing CreateEntity and of course its not working also ;) I believe the mistake is in the .d.ts file but I can't seem to find it.

Other functions of the this.Manager are working and autocompleted!

```
// Type definitions for Breeze 1.0
// Project: http://www.breezejs.com/
// Definitions by: Boris Yankov <https://github.com/borisyankov/>
// Definitions: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

// Updated Jan 14 2011 - Jay Traband (www.ideablade.com)


declare module BreezeCore {

    interface ErrorCallback {
        (error: Error): void;
    }

    interface IEnum {
        contains(object: any): bool;
        fromName(name: string): EnumSymbol;
        getNames(): string[];
        getSymbols(): EnumSymbol[];
    }

    class Enum implements IEnum {
        constructor(name: string, methodObj?: any);

        addSymbol(propertiesObj?: any): EnumSymbol;
        contains(object: any): bool;
        fromName(name: string): EnumSymbol;
        getNames(): string[];
        getSymbols(): EnumSymbol[];
        static isSymbol(object: any): bool;
        seal(): void;
    }

    class EnumSymbol {
        parentEnum: IEnum;

        getName(): string;
        toString(): string;
    }

    class Event {
        constructor(name: string, publisher: any, defaultErrorCallback?: ErrorCallback);

        static enable(eventName: string, target: any): void;
        static enable(eventName: string, target: any, isEnabled: bool): void;
        static enable(eventName: string, target: any, isEnabled: Function): void;

        static isEnabled(eventName: string, target: any): bool;
        publish(data: any, publishAsync?: bool, errorCallback?: ErrorCallback): void;
        publishAsync(data: any, errorCallback?: ErrorCallback): void;
        subscribe(callback?: (data: any) => void ): number;
        unsubscribe(unsubKey: number): bool;
    }
}

declare module Breeze {

    interface Entity {
        entityAspect: EntityAspect;
        entityType: EntityType;
    }

    interface ComplexObject {
        complexAspect: ComplexAspect;
        complexType: ComplexType;
    }

    interface IProperty {
        name: string;
        parentEntityType: EntityType;
        validators: Validator[];
        isDataProperty: bool;
        isNavigationProperty: bool;
    }

    interface IStructuralType {
        complexProperties: DataProperty[];
        dataProperties: DataProperty[];
        name: string;
        namespace: string;
        shortName: string;
        unmappedProperties: DataProperty[];
        validators: Validator[];
    }

    class AutoGeneratedKeyType {
        static Identity: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
        static KeyGenerator: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
        static None: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
    }

    class ComplexAspect {
        complexObject: ComplexObject;
        entityAspect: EntityAspect;
        parent: Object;
        parentProperty: DataProperty;
        propertyPath: string;
        originalValues: Object;
    }

    class ComplexType implements IStructuralType {
        complexProperties: DataProperty[];
        dataProperties: DataProperty[];
        name: string;
        namespace: string;
        shortName: string;
        unmappedProperties: DataProperty[];
        validators: Validator[];
        addProperty(dataProperty: DataProperty);
        getProperties(): DataProperty[];
    }

    class DataProperty implements IProperty {
        complexTypeName: string;
        concurrencyMode: string;
        dataType: DataTypeSymbol;
        defaultValue: any;
        fixedLength: bool;
        isComplexProperty: bool;
        isDataProperty: bool;
        isNavigationProperty: bool;
        isNullable: bool;
        isPartOfKey: bool;
        isUnmapped: bool;

        maxLength: number;
        name: string;
        nameOnServer: string;
        parentEntityType: EntityType;
        relatedNavigationProperty: NavigationProperty;
        validators: Validator[];
        constructor(config: DataPropertyOptions);
    }

    interface DataPropertyOptions {
        complexTypeName?: string;
        concurrencyMode?: string;
        dataType?: DataTypeSymbol;
        defaultValue?: any;
        fixedLength?: bool;
        isNullable?: bool;
        isPartOfKey?: bool;
        isUnmapped?: bool;
        maxLength?: number;
        name?: string;
        nameOnServer?: string;
        validators?: Validator[];
    }

    class DataService {
        adapterName: string;
        hasServerMetadata: bool;
        serviceName: string;
        constructor(config: DataServiceOptions);
    }

    interface DataServiceOptions {
        adapterName?: string;
        hasServerMetadata?: bool;
        serviceName?: string;
    }

    class DataTypeSymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
        defaultValue: any;
        isNumeric: bool;
    }
    interface DataType extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        Binary: DataTypeSymbol;
        Boolean: DataTypeSymbol;
        Byte: DataTypeSymbol;
        DateTime: DataTypeSymbol;
        Decimal: DataTypeSymbol;
        Double: DataTypeSymbol;
        Guid: DataTypeSymbol;
        Int16: DataTypeSymbol;
        Int32: DataTypeSymbol;
        Int64: DataTypeSymbol;
        Single: DataTypeSymbol;
        String: DataTypeSymbol;
        Time: DataTypeSymbol;
        Undefined: DataTypeSymbol;
        toDataType(typeName: string): DataTypeSymbol;
        parseDateFromServer(date: any): Date;

    }
    declare var DataType: DataType;

    class EntityActionSymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
    }
    interface EntityAction extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        AcceptChanges: EntityActionSymbol;
        Attach: EntityActionSymbol;
        AttachOnImport: EntityActionSymbol;
        AttachOnQuery: EntityActionSymbol;
        Clear: EntityActionSymbol;
        Detach: EntityActionSymbol;
        EntityStateChange: EntityActionSymbol;
        MergeOnImport: EntityActionSymbol;
        MergeOnSave: EntityActionSymbol;
        MergeOnQuery: EntityActionSymbol;
        PropertyChange: EntityActionSymbol;
        RejectChanges: EntityActionSymbol;
    }
    var EntityAction: EntityAction;

    class EntityAspect {
        entity: Entity;
        entityManager: EntityManager;
        entityState: EntityStateSymbol;
        isBeingSaved: bool;
        originalValues: any;

        propertyChanged: PropertyChangedEvent;
        validationErrorsChanged: ValidationErrorsChangedEvent;

        acceptChanges(): void;
        addValidationError(validationError: ValidationError): void;
        clearValidationErrors(): void;
        getKey(forceRefresh?: bool): EntityKey;

        getValidationErrors(): ValidationError[];
        getValidationErrors(property: string): ValidationError[];
        getValidationErrors(property: IProperty): ValidationError[];

        loadNavigationProperty(navigationProperty: string, callback?: Function, errorCallback?: Function): Promise;
        loadNavigationProperty(navigationProperty: NavigationProperty, callback?: Function, errorCallback?: Function): Promise;

        rejectChanges(): void;

        removeValidationError(validator: Validator): void;
        removeValidationError(validator: Validator, property: DataProperty): void;
        removeValidationError(validator: Validator, property: NavigationProperty): void;

        setDeleted(): void;
        setModified(): void;
        setUnchanged(): void;
        validateEntity(): bool;

        validateProperty(property: string, context?: any): bool;
        validateProperty(property: DataProperty, context?: any): bool;
        validateProperty(property: NavigationProperty, context?: any): bool;
    }

    class PropertyChangedEventArgs {
        entity: Entity;
        propertyName: string;
        oldValue: any;
        newValue: any;
    }

    class PropertyChangedEvent extends BreezeCore.Event {
        subscribe(callback?: (data: PropertyChangedEventArgs) => void ): number;
    }

    class ValidationErrorsChangedEventArgs {
        entity: Entity;
        added: ValidationError[];
        removed: ValidationError[];
    }

    class ValidationErrorsChangedEvent extends BreezeCore.Event {
        subscribe(callback?: (data: ValidationErrorsChangedEventArgs) => void ): number;
    }

    class EntityKey {
        constructor(entityType: EntityType, keyValue: any);
        constructor(entityType: EntityType, keyValues: any[]);

        equals(entityKey: EntityKey): bool;
        static equals(k1: EntityKey, k2: EntityKey): bool;
    }

    class EntityManager {
        dataService: DataService;
        keyGeneratorCtor: Function;
        metadataStore: MetadataStore;
        queryOptions: QueryOptions;
        saveOptions: SaveOptions;
        serviceName: string;
        validationOptions: ValidationOptions;

        entityChanged: EntityChangedEvent;
        // hasChanges: BreezeCore.Event;

        constructor(config?: EntityManagerOptions);
        constructor(config?: string);

        addEntity(entity: Entity): Entity;
        attachEntity(entity: Entity, entityState?: EntityStateSymbol): Entity;
        clear(): void;
        createEmptyCopy(): EntityManager;
        detachEntity(entity: Entity): bool;

        executeQuery(query: string, callback?: ExecuteQuerySuccessCallback, errorCallback?: ExecuteQueryErrorCallback): Promise;
        executeQuery(query: EntityQuery, callback?: ExecuteQuerySuccessCallback, errorCallback?: ExecuteQueryErrorCallback): Promise;

        executeQueryLocally(query: EntityQuery): Entity[];
        exportEntities(entities?: Entity[]): string;
        fetchEntityByKey(typeName: string, keyValue: any, checkLocalCacheFirst?: bool): Entity;
        fetchEntityByKey(typeName: string, keyValues: any[], checkLocalCacheFirst?: bool): Entity;
        fetchEntityByKey(entityKey: EntityKey): Entity;
        fetchMetadata(callback?: (schema: any) => void , errorCallback?: BreezeCore.ErrorCallback): Promise;
        generateTempKeyValue(entity: Entity): any;
        getChanges(): Entity[];
        getChanges(entityTypeName: string): Entity[];
        getChanges(entityTypeNames: string[]): Entity[];
        getChanges(entityType: EntityType): Entity[];
        getChanges(entityTypes: EntityType[]): Entity[];

        getEntities(entityTypeName: string, entityState?: EntityStateSymbol): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityTypeNames?: string[], entityState?: EntityStateSymbol): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityTypeName?: string, entityStates?: EntityStateSymbol[]): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityTypeNames?: string[], entityStates?: EntityStateSymbol[]): Entity[];

        getEntities(entityType: EntityType, entityState?: EntityStateSymbol): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityTypes?: EntityType[], entityState?: EntityStateSymbol): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityType?: EntityType, entityStates?: EntityStateSymbol[]): Entity[];
        getEntities(entityTypes?: EntityType[], entityStates?: EntityStateSymbol[]): Entity[];

        getEntityByKey(typeName: string, keyValue: any): Entity;
        getEntityByKey(typeName: string, keyValues: any[]): Entity;
        getEntityByKey(entityKey: EntityKey): Entity;

        hasChanges(): bool;
        hasChanges(entityTypeName: string): bool;
        hasChanges(entityTypeNames: string[]): bool;
        hasChanges(entityType: EntityType): bool;
        hasChanges(entityTypes: EntityType[]): bool;

        static importEntities(exportedString: string, config?: { mergeStrategy?: MergeStrategySymbol; }): EntityManager;
        importEntities(exportedString: string, config?: { mergeStrategy?: MergeStrategySymbol; }): EntityManager;

        rejectChanges(): Entity[];
        saveChanges(entities?: Entity[], saveOptions?: SaveOptions, callback?: SaveChangesSuccessCallback, errorCallback?: SaveChangesErrorCallback): Promise;
        setProperties(config: EntityManagerProperties): void;
    }

    interface EntityManagerOptions {
        serviceName?: string;
        dataService?: DataService;
        metadataStore?: MetadataStore;
        queryOptions?: QueryOptions;
        saveOptions?: SaveOptions;
        validationOptions?: ValidationOptions;
        keyGeneratorCtor?: Function;
    }

    interface EntityManagerProperties {
        serviceName?: string;
        dataService?: DataService;
        queryOptions?: QueryOptions;
        saveOptions?: SaveOptions;
        validationOptions?: ValidationOptions;
        keyGeneratorCtor?: Function;
    }

    interface ExecuteQuerySuccessCallback {
        (data: { results: Entity[]; query: EntityQuery; XHR: XMLHttpRequest; }): void;
    }

    interface ExecuteQueryErrorCallback {
        (error: { query: EntityQuery; XHR: XMLHttpRequest; }): void;
    }

    interface SaveChangesSuccessCallback {
        (saveResult: { entities: Entity[]; keyMappings: any; XHR: XMLHttpRequest; }): void;
    }

    interface SaveChangesErrorCallback {
        (error: { XHR: XMLHttpRequest; }): void;
    }

    class EntityChangedEventArgs {
        entity: Entity;
        entityAction: EntityActionSymbol;
        args: Object;
    }

    class EntityChangedEvent extends BreezeCore.Event {
        subscribe(callback?: (data: EntityChangedEventArgs) => void ): number;
    }

    class EntityQuery {
        entityManager: EntityManager;
        orderByClause: OrderByClause;
        parameters: Object;
        queryOptions: QueryOptions;
        resourceName: string;
        skipCount: number;
        takeCount: number;
        wherePredicate: Predicate;

        constructor(resourceName?: string);

        execute(callback?: ExecuteQuerySuccessCallback, errorCallback?: ExecuteQueryErrorCallback): Promise;
        executeLocally(): Entity[];
        expand(propertyPaths: string[]): EntityQuery;
        expand(propertyPaths: string): EntityQuery;
        static from(resourceName: string): EntityQuery;
        from(resourceName: string): EntityQuery;
        static fromEntities(entity: Entity): EntityQuery;
        static fromEntities(entities: Entity[]): EntityQuery;
        static fromEntityKey(entityKey: EntityKey): EntityQuery;
        static fromEntityNavigation(entity: Entity, navigationProperty: NavigationProperty): EntityQuery;
        inlineCount(enabled?: bool): EntityQuery;
        orderBy(propertyPaths: string): EntityQuery;
        orderBy(propertyPaths: string[]): EntityQuery;
        orderByDesc(propertyPaths: string): EntityQuery;
        orderByDesc(propertyPaths: string[]): EntityQuery;
        select(propertyPaths: string): EntityQuery;
        select(propertyPaths: string[]): EntityQuery;
        skip(count: number): EntityQuery;
        take(count: number): EntityQuery;
        top(count: number): EntityQuery;

        using(obj: EntityManager): EntityQuery;
        using(obj: MergeStrategySymbol): EntityQuery;
        using(obj: FetchStrategySymbol): EntityQuery;

        where(predicate: Predicate): EntityQuery;
        where(property: string, operator: string, value: any): EntityQuery;
        where(property: string, operator: FilterQueryOpSymbol, value: any): EntityQuery;
        where(predicate: FilterQueryOpSymbol): EntityQuery;
        withParameters(params: Object): EntityQuery;
    }

    interface OrderByClause {
    }

    class EntityStateSymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
        isAdded(): bool;
        isAddedModifiedOrDeleted(): bool;
        isDeleted(): bool;
        isDetached(): bool;
        isModified(): bool;
        isUnchanged(): bool;
        isUnchangedOrModified(): bool;
    }
    interface EntityState extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        Added: EntityStateSymbol;
        Deleted: EntityStateSymbol;
        Detached: EntityStateSymbol;
        Modified: EntityStateSymbol;
        Unchanged: EntityStateSymbol;
    }
    var EntityState: EntityState;

    class EntityType implements IStructuralType {
        autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
        complexProperties: DataProperty[];
        concurrencyProperties: DataProperty[];
        dataProperties: DataProperty[];
        defaultResourceName: string;
        foreignKeyProperties: DataProperty[];
        keyProperties: DataProperty[];
        metadataStore: MetadataStore;
        name: string;
        namespace: string;
        navigationProperties: NavigationProperty[];
        shortName: string;
        unmappedProperties: DataProperty[];
        validators: Validator[];

        constructor(config: MetadataStore);
        constructor(config: EntityTypeOptions);

        addProperty(property: IProperty): void;
        addValidator(validator: Validator, property?: IProperty): void;
        createEntity(initialValues?: Object): Entity;
        getDataProperty(propertyName: string): DataProperty;
        getEntityCtor(): Function;
        getNavigationProperty(propertyName: string): NavigationProperty;
        getProperties(): IProperty[];
        getProperty(propertyPath: string, throwIfNotFound?: bool): IProperty;
        getPropertyNames(): string[];
        setProperties(config: EntityTypeProperties): void;
        toString(): string;
    }

    interface EntityTypeOptions {
        shortName?: string;
        namespace?: string;
        autogeneratedKeyType?: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
        defaultResourceName?: string;
    }

    interface EntityTypeProperties {
        autogeneratedKeyType?: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
        defaultResourceName?: string;
    }

    class FetchStrategySymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
    }
    interface FetchStrategy extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        FromLocalCache: FetchStrategySymbol;
        FromServer: FetchStrategySymbol;
    }
    var FetchStrategy: FetchStrategy;

    class FilterQueryOpSymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
    }
    interface FilterQueryOp extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        Contains: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        EndsWith: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        Equals: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        GreaterThan: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        GreaterThanOrEqual: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        LessThan: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        LessThanOrEqual: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        NotEquals: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
        StartsWith: FilterQueryOpSymbol;
    }
    var FilterQueryOp: FilterQueryOp;

    class LocalQueryComparisonOptions {
        static caseInsensitiveSQL: LocalQueryComparisonOptions;
        static defaultInstance: LocalQueryComparisonOptions;

        constructor(config: { name?: string; isCaseSensitive?: bool; usesSql92CompliantStringComparison?: bool; });

        setAsDefault(): void;
    }

    class MergeStrategySymbol extends BreezeCore.EnumSymbol {
    }
    interface MergeStrategy extends BreezeCore.IEnum {
        OverwriteChanges: MergeStrategySymbol;
        PreserveChanges: MergeStrategySymbol;
    }
    var MergeStrategy: MergeStrategy;

    class MetadataStore {
        namingConvention: NamingConvention;

        constructor(config?: MetadataStoreOptions);
        addDataService(dataService: DataService): void;
        addEntityType(structuralType: IStructuralType): void;
        exportMetadata(): string;
        fetchMetadata(dataService: string, callback?: (data) => void , errorCallback?: BreezeCore.ErrorCallback): Promise;
        fetchMetadata(dataService: DataService, callback?: (data) => void , errorCallback?: BreezeCore.ErrorCallback): Promise;
        getDataService(serviceName: string): DataService;
        getEntityType(entityTypeName: string, okIfNotFound?: bool): IStructuralType;
        getEntityTypes(): IStructuralType[];
        hasMetadataFor(serviceName: string): bool;
        static importMetadata(exportedString: string): MetadataStore;
        importMetadata(exportedString: string): MetadataStore;
        isEmpty(): bool;
        registerEntityTypeCtor(entityTypeName: string, entityCtor: Function, initializationFn?: (entity: Entity) => void ): void;
        trackUnmappedType(entityCtor: Function, interceptor?: Function);
    }

    interface MetadataStoreOptions {
        namingConvention?: NamingConvention;
        localQueryComparisonOptions?: LocalQueryComparisonOptions;
    }

    class NamingConvention {
        static camelCase: NamingConvention;
        static defaultInstance: NamingConvention;
        static none: NamingConvention;

        constructor(config: NamingConventionOptions);

        clientPropertyNameToServer(clientPropertyName: string): string;
        clientPropertyNameToServer(clientPropertyName: string, property: IProperty): string;

        serverPropertyNameToClient(serverPropertyName: string): string;
        serverPropertyNameToClient(serverPropertyName: string, property: IProperty): string;

        setAsDefault();
    }

    interface NamingConventionOptions {
        serverPropertyNameToClient?: (name: string) => string;
        clientPropertyNameToServer?: (name: string) => string;
    }

    class NavigationProperty implements IProperty {
        associationName: string;
        entityType: EntityType;
        foreignKeyNames: string[];
        inverse: NavigationProperty;
        isDataProperty: bool;
        isNavigationProperty: bool;
        isScalar: bool;
        name: string;
        parentEntityType: EntityType;
        relatedDataProperties: DataProperty[];
        validators: Validator[];

        constructor(config: NavigationPropertyOptions);
    }

    interface NavigationPropertyOptions {
        name?: string;
        nameOnServer?: string;
        entityTypeName: string;
        isScalar?: bool;
        associationName?: string;
        foreignKeyNames?: string[];
        foreignKeyNamesOnServer?: string[];
        validators?: Validator[];
    }

    class Predicate {
        constructor(property: string, operator: string, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: bool);
        constructor(property: string, operator: FilterQueryOpSymbol, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: bool);

        and: PredicateMethod;
        static and: PredicateMethod;

        static create: PredicateMethod;

        static isPredicate(o: any): bool;

        static not(predicate: Predicate): Predicate;
        not(): Predicate;

        static or: PredicateMethod;
        or: PredicateMethod;

        toFunction(): Function;
        toString(): string;
        validate(entityType: EntityType): void;
    }

    interface PredicateMethod {
        (predicates: Predicate[]): Predicate;
        (...predicates: Predicate[]): Predicate;
        (property: string, operator: string, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: bool): Predicate;
        (property: string, operator: FilterQueryOpSymbol, value: any, valueIsLiteral?: bool): Predicate;
    }

    class Promise {
        fail(errorCallback: Function): Promise;
        fin(finallyCallback: Function): Promise;
        then(callback: Function): Promise;
    }

    class QueryOptions {
        static defaultInstance: QueryOptions;
        fetchStrategy: FetchStrategySymbol;
        mergeStrategy: MergeStrategySymbol;

        constructor(config?: QueryOptionsConfiguration);

        setAsDefault(): void;
        using(config: QueryOptionsConfiguration): QueryOptions;
        using(config: MergeStrategySymbol): QueryOptions;
        using(config: FetchStrategySymbol): QueryOptions;
    }

    interface QueryOptionsConfiguration {
        fetchStrategy?: FetchStrategySymbol;
        mergeStrategy?: MergeStrategySymbol;
    }

    class SaveOptions {
        allowConcurrentSaves: bool;
        static defaultInstance: SaveOptions;

        constructor(config?: { allowConcurrentSaves?: bool; });

        setAsDefault(): SaveOptions;
    }

    class ValidationError {
        context: any;
        errorMessage: string;
        property: IProperty;
        propertyName: string;
        validator: Validator;

        constructor(validator: Validator, context: any, errorMessage: string);
    }

    class ValidationOptions {
        static defaultInstance: ValidationOptions;
        validateOnAttach: bool;
        validateOnPropertyChange: bool;
        validateOnQuery: bool;
        validateOnSave: bool;

        constructor(config?: ValidationOptionsConfiguration);

        setAsDefault(): ValidationOptions;
        using(config: ValidationOptionsConfiguration): ValidationOptions;
    }

    interface ValidationOptionsConfiguration {
        validateOnAttach?: bool;
        validateOnSave?: bool;
        validateOnQuery?: bool;
        validateOnPropertyChange?: bool;
    }

    class Validator {
        static messageTemplates: any;

        constructor(name: string, validatorFn: ValidatorFunction, context?: any);

        static bool(): Validator;
        static byte(): Validator;
        static date(): Validator;
        static duration(): Validator;
        getMessage(): string;
        static guid(): Validator;
        static int16(): Validator;
        static int32(): Validator;
        static int64(): Validator;
        static maxLength(context: { maxLength: number; }): Validator;
        static number(): Validator;
        static required(): Validator;
        static string(): Validator;
        static stringLength(context: { maxLength: number; minLength: number; }): Validator;
        validate(value: any, context?: any): ValidationError;
    }

    interface ValidatorFunction {
        (value: any, context: ValidatorFunctionContext): void;
    }

    interface ValidatorFunctionContext {
        value: any;
        validatorName: string;
        displayName: string;
        messageTemplate: string;
        message?: string;
    }
}

declare var breeze : Breeze;
```

Comment: the only createEntity function i see in this code is lowercased while your question refers to CreateEntity with a capital C.  not sure if that's your problem...

Comment: In any case, `EntityType.createEntity` is in the definition file, but not `EntityManager.createEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used BreezeJS - so I'm basing this off of a glance at [the documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities).

It looks like the definition is missing from the definition file... for example, it looks like this should be possible:

```
var myThing = manager.createEntity('Test', { id:5 , name:'test'});
```

But the `EntityManager` class is missing this declaration:

```
createEntity(entityTypeName: string, propertyInitializer: {}): Entity;
```

I have submitted a [pull request to Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/390) for this.